# Replace word in <p> in <div> using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, text, replace

I have a document with the following structure:

```
<div id="notice" class="box generalbox">
<p>
This is some text.
</p>
</div>
```

I want to replace the word "some" with the word "My" using jQuery.

How do i do this?

I tried:

```
$("#notice").text().replace("some", "My");
```

But that didnt work...

UPDATE:
Thanks for all your replys. I used this solution to get this to work:

```
$("#notice p").text($("#notice p").text().replace("some", "My"));
```

Comment: Do you want to replace all instances of "some" with "My", or just the first? I know in your example there is only one instance, but what if it was something like "This is some text with some words; it was written sometime last week."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text

```
$("#notice p").text(function (_, ctx) {
    return ctx.replace("some", "My");
});
```

or

```
$("#notice p").text($("#notice p").text().replace("some", "My"));
```

or

```
var  p_tag = $("#notice p");
p_tag.text(p_tag.text().replace("some", "My"));
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without jquery?  With HTML or CSS for example?

Comment: The third options duplicates the element, the first option works perfectly

Answer (score 11):

You need to target the `p` tag inside the `#notice`:

```
$("#notice p").text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace("some", "My");
});
```

---

*Update 2020-03*

This same logic can now be made even simpler by using an arrow function:

```
$('#notice p').text((i, t) => t.replace('some', 'My'));
```

This will work in any browser except Internet Explorer.

Comment: You're welcome. You got plenty of upvotes without it, so just imagine how many you'll get _with_ it...

Answer (score 5):

This is an overkill but anyway:

```
function replaceNodeText() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(replaceNodeText.find, replaceNodeText.replace);
    } else {
        $(this).contents().each(replaceNodeText);
    }
}
replaceNodeText.find = "some";
replaceNodeText.replace = "my";
$("#notice").contents().each(replaceNodeText);
```

This function will preserve any html present inside the specified element. For example it will work on this HTML:

```
<div id="notice" class="box generalbox">
    <p>This is<br>some text.</p>
    <p>This is so<br>me text.</p>
    <p>This is <b>some</b> text.</p>
</div>
```

And produce the following output:

```
<div id="notice" class="box generalbox">
    <p>This is<br>my text.</p>
    <p>This is so<br>me text.</p>
    <p>This is <b>my</b> text.</p>
</div>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/XGz2Z/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = $("#notice p").text()
text = text.replace("some", "My");
$("#notice p").text(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, sure you will get your result.

```
$("#notice p").text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace("some", "My");
});
```

Comment: I found this absolutely the best / fastest solution to achieve my goal :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go a head and try this solution:

```
newtext = $("#notice p").text().replace("some", "My"); 
$("#notice p").text(newtext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#notice').html().replace("some", "my");
```

Comment: what is the problem ?? it gives me `<p>This is my text.</p>`

Comment: I'm reasonably sure the OP wants to update the page with the replaced text.

Answer (score 0):

Salmans answer works good, but if you have more than 1 word in a paragraph it wouldn't be replaced. So use this instead:
(with a regex that matches globally)

```
function replaceNodeText() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(replaceNodeText.regex, replaceNodeText.replace);
    } else {
        $(this).contents().each(replaceNodeText);
    }
}
replaceNodeText.regex = /some/g;
replaceNodeText.replace = "my";
$("#notice").contents().each(replaceNodeText);
```

Or use this:

(I just changed .replace(x,y) to .split(x).join(y), this is way faster than replace(), see [here](http://jsperf.com/split-vs-replace))

```
function replaceNodeText() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.split(replaceNodeText.find).join(replaceNodeText.replace);
    } else {
        $(this).contents().each(replaceNodeText);
    }
}
replaceNodeText.find = "some";
replaceNodeText.replace = "my";
$("#notice").contents().each(replaceNodeText);
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/XGz2Z/3/)