# Need help to identify why removing element and its contents in jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong with this jQuery code here?

```js
$('.deleter').click(function() {
    var toDelete = $(this).attr('stringStorage');
 $('.urls').text($('.urls').text().replace(toDelete, ''));
    $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.deleter {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.deleter:hover { background-color: orange; }

br { line-height: 22px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="urls">
  <span class="deleter" stringStorage="www.firsturl.com">x</span>www.firsturl.com<br>
  <span class="deleter" stringStorage="www.anothereurl.com">x</span>www.anothereurl.com<br>
  <span class="deleter" stringStorage="www.athirdurl.com">x</span>www.athirdurl.com<br>
</div>
```

It works fine at removing the `.deleter` element:

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/ku0t7mey/5/

But once `$('.urls').text($('.urls').text().replace(toDelete, ''));` in the element .deleter is removed but the contents (x) are left behind:

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/ku0t7mey/4/

**UPDATE**

I can get the whole function to work with [this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19318945/3377049).

But I will leave this question open for anyone who can answer why the code I used seems to remove all html elements within the targeted element.

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/ku0t7mey/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.nextSibling`, `.textContent` to set `#text` node adjacent to clicked `.deleter` element to empty string `""`.

```
$('.deleter').click(function(e) {
    var toDelete = $(this).data('stringStorage');
    this.nextSibling.textContent = "";
    $(this).remove();
});
```

You can also substitute using `data-*` attribute for custom attribute at `html`

```
<div class="urls">
  <span class="deleter" data-string-storage="www.firsturl.com">x</span>www.firsturl.com<br>
  <span class="deleter" data-string-storage="www.anothereurl.com">x</span>www.anothereurl.com<br>
  <span class="deleter" data-string-storage="www.athirdurl.com">x</span>www.athirdurl.com<br>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ku0t7mey/8/

you could alternatively use `.contents()`, `.filter()`, `.trim()`, `.add()` to remove the `#text` node at same call where `this` is removed from `document`

```
 $(".urls").contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() === toDelete
 }).add(this).remove();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ku0t7mey/12/

Comment: Gee, you made it look easy. Thanks very much. I'll be learning a lot from this as I reference it many times in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/ku0t7mey/7/

Modify the HTML like:

```
<div class="urls">
<div><span class="deleter" stringStorage="www.firsturl.com">x</span>www.firsturl.com</div>
<div>  <span class="deleter" stringStorage="www.anothereurl.com">x</span>www.anothereurl.com</div>
  <div><span class="deleter" stringStorage="www.athirdurl.com">x</span>www.athirdurl.com</div>sss
</div>
```

JS like:

```
$('.deleter').click(function() {
    var toDelete = $(this).attr('stringStorage');
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ish, thanks for your answer but I should have mentioned that I couldn't mess with the html structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ku0t7mey/10/)

HTML

```
<div class="urls">
<div class="delete">
  <span class="deleter" stringStorage="www.firsturl.com">x</span>www.firsturl.com<br>
</div>
  <div class="delete">
    <span class="deleter" stringStorage="www.anothereurl.com">x</span>www.anothereurl.com<br>
  </div>
<div class="delete">
  <span class="deleter" stringStorage="www.athirdurl.com">x</span>www.athirdurl.com<br>
</div>

</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    var toDelete = $(this).attr('stringStorage');
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kumar, I forgot to emphasize it was just the jquery I needed help with and couldn't adjust the html..